# Omitting date when exporting from org-mode

Tags: emacs, datetime, org-mode

How can I omit the date from being displayed when exporting to LaTeX from emacs org-mode?

This (within the .org file) works to omit the date when exporting to ascii:

```
#+OPTIONS: timestamp nil
```

But it doesn't take effect when exporting to LaTeX.

Nor does this work:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :date nil
```

Answer (score 6):

OK, so it was pretty simple.

This in the .org file:

```
#+DATE:
```

Gives you this in the .tex file:

```
\date{}
```

Guess that would have to be the best solution ...

Answer (score 2):

You made a slightly mistake in the options syntax. It should be:

```
#+OPTIONS: date:nil
```

Comment: This seems more like a comment. Please test and explain your solution.

Comment: @TeXnician edited to make it more clear as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#+OPTIONS: date: nil
```

or

```
#+DATE: nil
```

or

```
* Local Variables
Local Variables:
org-export-with-date: nil
End:
```

All these will result in `\date{}` in .tex file

In my case, this was undesirable. Then, every time, I needed to delete that line of my .tex file after exporting it.

Here is the workaround I came up with:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\date}{}
```